# Intersection of translation of positiv measure set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that Lebesgue measure of $E$, denoted by $m(E)$, is positive.

Q) Does there exist any $l>0$ such that $$ m\left(\cap_{t\in [-l,l]}E+t\right)>0?$$

Comment: @EikeSchulte Oh yeah, I don't now what i thought, deleted my comment

Comment: Hint: Try thinking about it the “other way around”, i.e. find a set $N$ of measure $0$ such that $E' := \bigcup_{t \in [-l, l]} (N + t)$ has measure greater than $1$ for any $l > 0$. Then make a slight modification to $E'$ to obtain $E$.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I (implicitly) claimed that the assertion is wrong, i.e. that there is a set $E$ of positive measure for which no such $l > 0$ exists. My hint was intended as a way to find such a set $E$ without immediately giving it away (this question seems like homework, so I don’t want to give a complete answer right away). I think finding a set $N$ with the property in my previous comment might be helpful to solving the problem and easier than finding $E$ directly.

Comment: Consider a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set),

Comment: @Paul Sinclair can you elaborate why so?

Comment: The complement of the fat Cantor set is dense.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair are you leading me to some famous theorem? I am getting some intuitive idea that the intersection will be empty. Any help is highly welcome.

Comment: I am thinking that, Let $E$ be the fat cantor set obtaining from $[0,1]$ by  removing $1/4^n$ interval at each $n$ step. There will be some integer $k$ for which the set $E_k$(obtained at $k'$th step of the process ) contains interval of length less than $l.$ Then the required intersection for $E_k$ will be empty. Hence the intersection will be empty fir $E$. Is that my line of argument correct? Also let me know your thought. Thanks

Comment: You are overthinking it. In fact, I overthought it in coming up with the fat cantor set as an example. An easier example would be just $E = [0,1]\setminus \Bbb Q$ - the set of irrational numbers in the unit interval. That set has measure $1$, but for any $l$, the intersection will be empty, since for any element $x\in E$, there is a $t < l$ such that $x + t$ is rational.

Comment: Ahhh. Right. Another question rises from your comment: Is the above question true if we replace positive measure by nowhere dense?